# Intelij Ultimate 2019.2 JAXB

Tags: intellij-idea, jaxb

I have read how to generate a schema from a java class but the menu items mention dont exist. Information is given on how to enable the Web Services plug in which it says is built in, but I cant find it. I expect this is why the menu item under tools do not appear when the source file is open in the editor.

I cannot find the any plugin for JAXB.

The instructions I am trying to follow are at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-xml-schema-from-java-code.html

At
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-xml-schema-from-java-using-jaxb-dialog.html

It says "This functionality is provided via the WebServices bundled plugin, which is enabled by default." but I dont see it in the list of installed plugins!

Must be doing something wrong but now out of ideas for what to try next.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The plugin name is **Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS)** and **Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)**. Also make sure you are using Ultimate Edition. Then focus the Java class in Editor - the Tools | JAXB menu should become available.

Comment: Thanks knew it something simple :)

Comment: Try with selecting the file and then pressing double shift to Search Everywhere. Search for JAXB.